# Upload to azure blob container failed to authenticate the request

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, xamarin.android

I'm receiving this error when uploading to a container on azure:

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

**And I know the problem is caused by different time zones.**

But in my application I can't depend on timezone to make the hole thing work. I need a solution that ignores timezone to send the files to the container.

I'm not using SAS.

This is my code to upload:

```
    public async Task<bool> SendPhotosAsync(int examID)
    {
        try
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cts.CancelAfter(Constants.SendExamPhotosAsyncTimeout);

            foreach (var image in GetExamFacePhotos(examID))
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(image);

                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Constants.AzureBlobStorageConnectionString);

                // Create the blob client.
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(Constants.AzureBlobContainerExamFacePhotos);

                // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

                // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
                using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(image))
                {
                   if (fileStream.Length > 0)
                   {
                       await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream, fileStream.Length, null, null, null, cts.Token);
                   }
                }
           }

           return true;
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        throw new Exception(_context.GetString(Resource.String.error_task_canceled));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception(_context.GetString(Resource.String.error_send_exam_media));
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

To reproduce what @Gaurav said, I changed the device GMT to 0 and keep the time for my current GMT (-3), GMT-0 09:02 and I got this on `ExtendedErrorInformation`:

> Request date header too old: 'Mon, 11 Mar 2019 09:02:25 GMT'

Azure checks both time and GMT of the request. If doesn't match, the error is shown.

Changing to GMT-4 and setting the time to its correct time zone, GMT-4 08:15, **the request was completed successfully**.

So, time zone doesn't matter since the time match its time zone.

Comment: Please check the time on the machine on which this code is running. Timezone difference won't cause this error, clock skewness will (+/- 15 minutes is allowed). Other reason could be incorrect account key.

Comment: @GauravMantri thank you for your response. But if I want to ignore the time as well, how can I do that?

Comment: If by ignoring time you mean ignoring clock skewness, I don't think you can do that. It's a security mechanism built into Storage REST API to prevent "replay attacks". As mentioned above, some clock skewness (+/- 15 minutes) is allowed but beyond that you will get 403 error.

Comment: Ok, that's a problem. Some states here in Brazil has different time zones. The Azure server stays in the state of São Paulo where the timezone is GMT-3, and the state of Amazonas, for example, has GMT-4. And this is causing the error said above. How can I solve this? Using SAS? I am reproducing this error locally, by changing the GMT of the device. It's not an account key problem.

Comment: In Azure everything is GMT (or UTC) so timezone difference won't make a difference. The SDK converts the local date/time in UTC and sends it to Azure. I would still recommend that you take a look at date/time on the machine where your code is running and make sure it is not off. Also, take a look at error details. Usually you will find more information in there. I think the property you may want to take a look at `ExtendedErrorInformation` (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSAsA.png). It should give you more details about the 403 error. Please update your question with what you see there.

Comment: @GauravMantri Question updated! Understood what you said. Thank you very much for your time!